# mySql database has sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104e18ea0 as output in table

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

I have a table named rank

```
 id  Name 
 1    Roger
 2    Tom
```

Another table named PersonId. Here I am trying to trying to select name and add id in the personId Table.

```
def getRank(teamName):
    name = c.execute(ids = c.execute("SELECT id From rank where Name = '%s';" % Name)
    print "str val of rank: ",name.fetchall()[0][0],
    return str(name.fetchall()[0][0])
```

If I enter "Roger", I am expecting

```
1
```

In the common line interface I see:

```
str val of rank:  1
```

But in the database it prints out as

"sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104e18ea0".

Currently, PersonId table looks like

```
id
```

c.execute(insert into PersonId (id) values (?),[getRank('Roger')])

After execution, table looks like:

```
    id
sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104e18ea0
sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x104e18ea0
```

I am not sure why I am getting address of object location instead of actual value

Any idea or help will be appreciated

Comment: Your `getRank()` function does not return anything, so I would expect the database value to be `None`.

Comment: I have that, just missed that line while copy pasting, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Just need to change:

```
str(name.fetchall()[0][0])
       to
name.fetchall()[0][0]
```